# how to return sharedpreferences's value?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'm using sharedpreferences to store user's Governorate. It's already saved in an xml file, but always returns default value

How can I return SharedPreferences's value?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNij7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsdWm.png)

> Kotlin

```
governorate_main.setOnClickListener {
      val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_photo, null)
      val alertBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      alertBuilder.setView(view)
      val alertDialog = alertBuilder.create()
      alertDialog.show()
      view.save_governorate.setOnClickListener {
            mShared = getSharedPreferences("mShared", 0)
            val radioId = view.radioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId
            radioButton = view?.findViewById(radioId)
            radioSelected = radioButton?.text.toString()
            val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor = mShared!!.edit()
            editor.putString("governorate", radioSelected).toString()
            editor.apply()
            alertDialog.dismiss()
       }
       val databack: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("mShared", 0)
       governorate.text = databack.getString("governorte", "Please choose your country")
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause:** You are using 2 difference keys to store and retrieve a value from SharedPreferences, `governorate` is different from `governorte`.

**Solution:** You should define the key as a `static constant` then using it when store and retrieve a value.

```
companion object {
    val PREF_GOVERNORATE: String = "governorate"
}
```

Store:

```
editor.putString(PREF_GOVERNORATE, radioSelected).toString()
```

Retrieve:

```
databack.getString(PREF_GOVERNORATE, "Please choose your country")
```

Comment: you're right. i did so but i still have a problem "                  java.lang.NullPointerException
"

Comment: the error is in this line        governorate.text = databack.getString("governorte", "Please choose your country")

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I need full logcat, you can edit the question and add the logcat error.

Comment: Make sure `governorate` has been initialized before set text on it.

Comment: i did so ,line 61        governorate.text = databack.getString("governorte", "Please choose your country")

Answer (score 0):

You made a spelling mistake, you're saving as `governorate` but trying to fetch `governorte`

Also it probably isn't a good idea to nest click listeners

Comment: you're right. i did so but i still have a problem " java.lang.NullPointerException "

Comment: @mola you're going to have to rearrange your code, because at the moment it's not going to work.  

I'd suggest moving `view.save_governorate.setOnClickListener {...` outside of `governorate_main.setOnClickListener {...` and are you sure the `governorate` view is actually not null?